# Precedence vs. Optional suffices

Tags: antlr4

We have been using ANTLR 4.7.2 to design a language that has optional modifiers on one of the operators in a list ordered by precedence.  A simple example is the following grammar:

```
simple1
: simple1 K_AND simple1
| simple1 K_BUT K_NOT simple1
| simple1 K_OR simple1
| WHOLE_NUMBER
;
```

This yields the proper precedence (`AND` over `BUT NOT` over `OR`.)

[image: good precedence]

If we add an optional suffix to the AND case:

```
simple1
    : simple1 K_AND simple1 filt?
    | simple1 K_BUT K_NOT simple1
    | simple1 K_OR simple1
    | WHOLE_NUMBER
;

filt : K_PM;
```

We lose the precedence of the operators.

[image: lost precedence]

Is there a way to do this cleanly in one rule?  Our previous solution was to separate the AND option into a separate rule.

Answer (score 1):

We came up with a simple answer:

```
simple1:
      simple1 K_AND simple1 filt
    | simple1 K_AND simple1
    | simple1 K_BUT K_NOT simple1
    | simple1 K_OR simple1
    | WHOLE_NUMBER
;

filt : K_PM;
```

Kept the precedence rules correct.

Comment: That's an interesting finding. I would usually convert such code to use an optional `filt`. Now I know better, thanks.